# Asymmetric random walks: eigenvalues and spectral gap

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, random-walk

For a reversible finite-state Markov chain, the second largest eigenvalue determines how fast the Markov chain converges to its stationary distribution.

A few questions (e.g, [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204077/mixing-time-for-a-random-walk-on-an-interval), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56624/can-the-following-probabilistic-argument-about-eigenvalues-be-made-rigorous/56632#56632)) refer to Chapter 12 (examples starting on page 165) of  the book [Markov Chains and Mixing Times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204077/mixing-time-for-a-random-walk-on-an-interval) by Levin, Peres, and Wilmer, where the eigenvalues of some *symmetric* random walks are found.

Are there similar results available for *asymmetric* random walks? I am struggling to derive what the eigenvalues are in that case.

Comment: In the asymmetric case, the eigenvalues can have nonzero imaginary parts, which I suppose makes the notion of "spectral gap" need improvement.

Comment: If the random walk is reversible (which puts some constraints on the transition probabilities), then the eigenvalues are real.

Comment: I remember reading [this paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/fmmc.pdf), where they focus mostly on the symmetric case, though they consider the non-symmetric case (in section 6), too.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good paper.